# Unable to resolve library dependency concerning dex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, compatibility, dex

I have upgraded from  Android Support Library to Androidx. Since then I am having this error when I run the program:

> "Program type already present: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture".

```
I have tried adding the following line to build.gradle file but still the error persists.

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

> I am attaching my build.gradle file code as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {     
    commpileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test.free'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 48
        versionName '11.1'
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.free
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.free

        }    
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    productFlavors {
    }    
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev206-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

> I am not able to resolve this issue and therefore need some assistant.

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app's module build.gradle:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

It happens because some dependencies use `com.google.guava:guava` and some use `com.google.guava:listenablefuture` and together they causes a dependency conflict.